matplotlib animation not working with xlwings
i am having issues with matplotlib animations when using xlwings, example from matplotlib:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import xlwings as xw

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i / 50))  # update the data.
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, interval=20, blit=True, save_count=50)

plt.show()

i get the following error:
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.

this works fine when i do not use xlwings

I was able to fix this by setting the backend after importing xlwings:
import xlwings as xw

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

